# Is it possible to have an SSL connection to a postgresql db using Asyncpg?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, asyncpg

I've been trying to deploy a discord bot on heroku for days, I use a postgresql database hosted on aws with heroku postgres. I've had many problems trying to connect with ssl to the database using asyncpg, I could find the solutions to some of the problems on the internet but I am now stuck with this error :

`2020-12-28T10:33:11.856268+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise exceptions.InterfaceError(`

`` 2020-12-28T10:33:11.856403+00:00 app[worker.1]: asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: `ssl` parameter can only be enabled for TCP addresses, got a UNIX socket path: '/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432' ``

This is how I connect to the database :

```
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context(cafile='rds-ca-2019-eu-west-1.pem')
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    bot.con = await asyncpg.create_pool(dsn=DATABASE_URI, ssl=ctx)

    ...

    bot.loop.run_until_complete(create_db_pool())
```

I have no clue of why I have that error, when trying to deploy my code on Heroku. I don't have that problem running it from my computer..
Tried to read the asyncpg documentation, not much came out of it. I don't know why it's using unix sockets and didn't really understand how it works, but I've read that asyncpg is supposed to support ssl connexion now...
Do you think there is a way to make this work, or should I just switch to psycopg2 ?

Comment: Apparently DATABASE_URI is wrong.  It does not appear to correctly specify a host, and so defaults to a unix socket instead.

Comment: @jjanes Gosh.. Really thank you for your help I don't know how it's possible but I apparently managed to copy the URL wrong at least twice.. I have spend so much time struggling to deploy this, thought it would never happen. I am so grateful and happy right now, really thank you for your answer !!! You're so cool :D